# Guardar json en un modelo angular1 (ionic1)

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic

tengo una consulta en angular. necesito acceder a los datos de un json

```
[
  {
    "gift": [
      {
        "description": "Recibe un pichel de te gratis!!",
        "name": "Te para Todos",
        "cod": "Te01",
        "poll": 6,
        "id": 5
      }
    ],
    "question": [
      {
        "header": "Que tan seguido viene a nuestro local?",
        "poll": 6,
        "id": 16
      },
      {
        "header": "quisiera mas promociones?",
        "poll": 6,
        "id": 17
      }
    ],
    "name": "PH01",
    "id": 6
  }
]
```

principalmente no se como acceder a los header dentro de question, la cantidad de question es variable en todas las consultas. mi modelo es este:

```
angular.module( 'pollmodel', [] )

.factory( 'Poll', function () {
    function Poll( name, ) {

    }
    Poll.build = function ( data ) {
        if( !data ) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Poll( data.name )
    }

    Poll.prototype.toJson = function () {
        return angular.toJson( this );
    };

    Poll.fromJsonBunch = function ( data ) {
        if( angular.isArray( data ) ) {
            return data.map( film.build ).filter( boolean );
        }
        return film.build( data );
    }

    return Poll;
} )
```

esta incompleto. porque no he sabido como completarlo para que reciba apropiadamente el json.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas hacer un map para sacar los campos header.

```
var datos = [{
"gift": [
  {
    "description": "Recibe un pichel de te gratis!!",
    "name": "Te para Todos",
    "cod": "Te01",
    "poll": 6,
    "id": 5
  }
],
"question": [
  {
    "header": "Que tan seguido viene a nuestro local?",
    "poll": 6,
    "id": 16
  },
  {
    "header": "quisiera mas promociones?",
    "poll": 6,
    "id": 17
  }
],
"name": "PH01",
"id": 6 }];

// Sacar los headers de las questions, crea un array con los headers
var headers = datos[0].question.map(function(q) {
                    return q.header; //devolver el campo header de cada question
                });
```

Y si hubiera más de un elemento en el array tendrías que hacer lo mismo para sacar los múltiples questions con un map.